# Using AWK to change the field value in a line based on the patterns in the next lines

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a text file (A.txt) like:

```
A B C D
.
.
SS (ii)
.
A B C D
.
.
.
.
A B C D
```

I would like to assign a new value (for example BB) to the second field of a record matching "A B C D" if the pattern "SS (ii)"  appears in the third line after "A B C D". Something like:

```
A BB C D
.
.
SS (ii)
.
A B C D
.
.
.
.
A B C D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
                      if(a[i]~/SS \(ii\)/ && a[i-3]~/A B C D/)
                        sub(/B/,"BB",a[i-3]);for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' file
```

this should do.

Note

- this gives you my idea, you can do more with your real data, E.g. split the line into fields and do update, instead of `sub(/B/,"BB..)` etc.
- the above solution processes the file once, saves all lines in memory then does the substitution logic and ouput. You can also read the file twice, first get those `SS \(..)` line number, 2nd time check and update the line. Choose the way you like.

Comment: What if the file is very large? Will not we run out of memory?

Comment: @user3684042 process it twice then. I mention how can it work. (Note [2])

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if (/A B C D/) f=NR; if ($0~/SS \(ii\)/ && f && NR==f+3) {h[NR-3]=1;f=""};next} h[FNR] {$2="BB"}1' file{,}
A BB C D
.
.
SS (ii)
.
A B C D
.
.
.
.
A B C D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/SS \(ii\)/) ss[NR]++; next} /A B C D/ && ss[FNR+3]{$2=BB} 1' file file
```